# Trouble installing 'ecospat. package when it is in a folder on my computer. Error: 'C:/Users/user/AppData/.../ecospat_3.5.tar.gz' is not a directory

Tags: r

When trying to install `ecospat`, I get the following message"

```
* removing 'D:/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/ecospat'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ecospat’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp4iWy3v\downloaded_packages’
```

When I check that file path, ecospat is there as: ecospat_3.5.tar.gz with 1503 KB

`library(ecospat)` gives

```
Error in library(ecospat) : there is no package called ‘ecospat’
```

I did a bit of googling , so tried

```
devtools::install("C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp4iWy3v/downloaded_packages/ecospat_3.5.tar.gz")
```

With this result:

```
Error: 'C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp4iWy3v/downloaded_packages/ecospat_3.5.tar.gz' is not a directory.
```

Now I am stuck. Any suggestions please?

Edit: This is the total of what I get when I use `install.packages`

```
> install.packages("ecospat")
Installing package into ‘D:/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  dependencies ‘biomod2’, ‘randomForest’ are not available

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
        binary source needs_compilation
ecospat  3.2.1    3.5             FALSE

installing the source package ‘ecospat’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/ecospat_3.5.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1538899 bytes (1.5 MB)
downloaded 1.5 MB

ERROR: dependencies 'biomod2', 'randomForest' are not available for package 'ecospat'
* removing 'D:/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/ecospat'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ecospat’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpmudBWY\downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: when using `install.packages`, did you get any other messages before the warning message e.g. before *had non-zero exit status*?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @user20650. I have edited my question to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks. Did you say no to installing from source? It will be easier to just install the binaries, this will (should) take care of the dependencies  for you e.g. biomod2', 'randomForest' and many others fhat ecospat has

Comment: ah.... [biomod2](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/biomod2/index.html) and [randomForest](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForest/index.html) require R (≥ 4.1) and you are on R4.0. Can you upgrade?

Comment: I can upgrade. I will do that and see how I go thanks.

Comment: Thanks so much @user20650. That all worked and I have completed an evaluation. The fact that I have no idea where the results got stored is beside the point. :( I can sort hat out!!

Comment: You're welcome. (If you are saving some results but not explicitly setting a path to where you want them to be saved then they will likely be saved to the default working directory; you can see this with `getwd()`)

Comment: Thanks @user20650. I found them fairly quickly! Just sent them again to where I wanted them!!